# Parallel output not the same as sequential output

Tags: fortran, openmp, private

I am trying to parallelize my code for least squares fit. The sequential verion gives correct answer. The parallel version compiles and runs but my answers are not correct. I was wondering if I could get any help here.

Writing the code here:

```
PROGRAM learn_parallel
use workArrays_mod
use real_precision
!$ USE OMP_LIB, ONLY: OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS, OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM
IMPLICIT NONE

real(kind=r8), dimension(:,:,:), allocatable :: x, coeffs
real(kind=r8), dimension(:), allocatable :: time, alphastar
real(kind=r8) :: xbarlim1
integer :: ix, iy, it, IERR, nt, ncols
integer :: ilaenv

nt = 6
ncols = 2
allocate(x(100, 100, nt), time(nt), coeffs(100,100,ncols))
x = 0
do ix=1,100
  do iy=1,100
     x(ix, iy, :) = (/ 1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 4.0, 4.9, 5.9 /)
  end do
end do
time = (/ 1.2, 2.3, 3.0, 3.8, 4.7, 5.9 /)

allocate (tmp_mat(6, ncols), rtmp_vec1(6), rtmp_vec2(6), &
       &  itmp_vec1(6), itmp_vec2(6))
nb = ILAENV(1,'DGELS','N',size(tmp_mat, 1),size(tmp_mat, 2),-1,-1)

CALL OMP_SET_DYNAMIC(.FALSE.)
!$OMP PARALLEL DO  &
!The SHARED list contains shared variables across all threads.
!$OMP& SHARED(x, time, xbarlim1, coeffs) &
!The PRIVATE list contains uninitialized variables every 
!thread should have a private copy of.
!$OMP& PRIVATE(alphastar, IERR) &
!$OMP& DEFAULT (NONE) 
do ix = 1, 100
  do iy = 1,1  !100
     print *, OMP_GET_NUM_THREADS(), ",",  OMP_GET_THREAD_NUM()
     call lsfit(time, x(ix, iy, :), 0, xbarlim1, alphastar, IERR)
     coeffs(ix, iy, :) = alphastar
     deallocate (alphastar)
     print *, coeffs(ix, iy, :)
  end do
end do
!$OMP END PARALLEL DO
deallocate (tmp_mat, rtmp_vec1, rtmp_vec2, itmp_vec1, itmp_vec2)
deallocate (x, time, coeffs)

CONTAINS

SUBROUTINE lsfit(t, u, K, xbarlim1, alphaStar, IERR)
USE workarrays_mod
USE REAL_PRECISION
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: K
REAL(KIND=R8), INTENT(IN) :: t(:), u(:)
REAL(KIND=R8), INTENT(IN)     :: xbarlim1
INTEGER             :: i, j, ccol, ncols, lwork, DeAllocateStatus
INTEGER             :: info, IERR, sz, m, mn
REAL(KIND=R8)       :: sigma, tau1, detR1, detXtX
REAL(KIND=R8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE:: X
REAL(KIND=R8), DIMENSION(:),  ALLOCATABLE :: work
REAL(KIND=R8), DIMENSION(:),  ALLOCATABLE, intent(inout) :: alphaStar

M = size(t, 1)
ncols = 2
ALLOCATE (X(m, ncols))
ALLOCATE (alphaStar(ncols))

X(:,1) = (/ (1, i = 1,M) /)
X(:,2) = t

lwork = min(M, ncols) +  max(max(M, ncols), 1) * nb 
ALLOCATE (work(lwork)) 
!use QR factorization to solve the system, way more stable
!drawback of DGELS: It is assumed that A has full rank. 
tmp_mat(1:M, 1:ncols) = X
rtmp_vec1(1:M) = u

CALL DGELS('N', M, ncols, 1,tmp_mat(1:M, 1:ncols),M, &
           &  rtmp_vec1(1:M),M, work(1:lwork),  &
           &  lwork, info)
alphaStar = rtmp_vec1(1:ncols) 

DEALLOCATE (X, work, stat = DeAllocateStatus)
END SUBROUTINE lsfit
END PROGRAM learn_parallel
```

The module workArray that I use above is as follows:

```
MODULE WorkArrays_MOD
USE REAL_PRECISION
IMPLICIT NONE

INTEGER, DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: itmp_vec1, itmp_vec2
REAL(KIND=R8), DIMENSION(:), ALLOCATABLE :: rtmp_vec1, rtmp_vec2
REAL(KIND=R8), DIMENSION(:,:), ALLOCATABLE :: tmp_mat
INTEGER ::  nb

END MODULE
```

The correct answer to the linear regression problem would be 
(-0.1432, 1.0506) which is what I get when I run this code pre-parallelization.

Comment: It is good to supply a working code and not `!assign something here.` so that we can test it ourselves. Also, if you have an error message with the `SHARED` clause, you should show the exact code which produces the error.

Comment: But I am afraid that the `private(rMatrix_2D, rVector1_1D)` is not in effect inside `sub1` and you may have a race condition there.

Comment: Regarding the feedback in your second comment, how do i make private in effect inside sub1? Because, in reality, my subroutine in not that small. Basically, I have a 3D matrix (corresponding to a collection of images, of the same scene, taken at different time points). The time series for each pixel is processed independently. That said I want to run the pixels in parallel.

Comment: I updated my post with values assigned to x and time. Sorry, I was reading the values from images and was confused about cooking up an example ...

Comment: There are still some syntax errors in the example, please make sure it can be compiled. Global working variables are generally not a good idea. `threadprivate` might help (or not).

Comment: Also, `pixel_x` and `pixel_y` are undefined in your example. Please be sure to use `implicit none`!

Comment: Hi, I have cleaned up my question. The code posted here is now proper --- with a sane example, properly compiling and running and the sequential version gives correct answer. Do you think you can help now?

Comment: What don't you put some I/o in and see where it differs from the non parallel version?

Comment: I did ... those workarrays frequently do not get the correct values. But removing the workArrays would mean that many allocations and deallocations.